# C++ template point of instantiation confusion

Tags: c++, templates

I'm a little confused about the point of instantiation in C++.  Consider the following code (which compiles fine under VC++2012):

```
struct Foo;

template <class T> Foo* Create() { return new Foo; }

Foo* MyFoo = Create<int>();

// (A) I expected point of instantiation to be here

struct Foo {};

// (B) But it appears to be here instead
```

I expected the point of instantiation to be point (A) above, but clearly this is not the case (since Foo is an incomplete type at point (A)).  Can anyone explains why this compiles?  Is this standard behavior or a quirk of MSVC?

**Edit**: To clarify, what I really want to know is: is this a valid program or not?  Should the compiler accept it or not and why?  (Clearly, if the compiler accepts the program and it should not, then this is a non-conforming behavior of MSVC.)

Comment: How do you know it's in (B)?

Comment: This looks like another effect of the non-compliant lookup of MSVC.. [clang++ rejects this program](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c23417fa7ae10738)

Comment: @Baum mit Augen: Because if the point of instantiation is (A), then the following line would irrelevant.  But if I remove that line, then the code will fail to compile (as I would expect).

Comment: `template <class T> Foo* Create() { return new Foo; }` There's nothing specified depending on `T` actually`?!?

Comment: This example is greatly distilled from my actual code.

Comment: @PeterRuderman _'This example is greatly distilled from my actual code'_ Make your sample a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) then as usual. Your question is unclear for me, actually.

Comment: This is a MVCE.  It's the minimal example demonstrating the confusing compiler behavior I have observed.

Comment: @PeterRuderman If you change `Create()` from a function template to a regular function, VS2013 rejects the code. As dyp already commented, I think this is a side effect of MSVC not implementing two phase name lookup.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I think the question is: Why does the compiler not fail in the line `Foo* MyFoo = Create<int>();`? It does not have the definition of `Foo` at that point.

Comment: @RSahu [At least VS2013](http://rise4fun.com/vcpp) doesn't fail either to compile, if this really makes up a MVCE (still don't think so) :P ...

Comment: @Praetorian: Yes, this is quite possible.  What I was really hoping is that someone with a strong understanding of the standard could explain whether the compiler should accept or reject this program and why.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, it must be a VS2012 defect then. What would you add to make it a MCVE?

Comment: http://ideone.com/TgE7HR check this out. It doesn't compile on GCC.

Comment: @RSahu Which defect? _'(which compiles fine under VC++2012)'_ so it does for VC++2013 as shown with the linked online compiler service?

Comment: @PeterRuderman *[expr.new]* states that the type in a `new` expression must be a complete type, and `Foo` is incomplete where `Create()` is instantiated. So it seems pretty clear to me your example is ill-formed.

Comment: It's ok for Foo to be undefined at the point Create() is defined (because Create is a template function).  But it must defined at the point Create is instantiated.

Comment: @PeterRuderman Sorry, that's what I meant

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The defect is that VS doesn't implement the two-phase look-up correctly. I am pretty sure the code is not valid.

Comment: I'm not convinced that this is a consequence of two-phase look-up (though it could be).  One interesting discovery I've made is that the code does compile on GCC 4.1.2, but not on recent versions.

Comment: Doesn't [this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/temp.point#7) apply? *A specialization for a function template (...) may have multiple POIs within a translation unit, and in addition to the POIs described above, for any such specialization that has a POI within the translation unit, the end of the translation unit is also considered a POI. (...) If two different POIs give a template specialization different meanings according to the one-definition rule, the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.*
If so, MSVC IS conforming. Because the program is ill-formed NDR.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start at the top. The definition of `Create()` is not valid because it tries to allocate memory for an incomplete type in the body. However, you could have declared this function here and defined it later.

The declaration of `Create<int>()` is fine -- declaring a pointer to an incomplete type, or a function that returns one, is allowed.

Of course, if you remove the definition of Foo from the end of your code, the compiler reaches the end and realizes it never saw a definition of the Foo type. Then, instead of being an incomplete type preceding a definition, your Foo struct is just undefined and any code that refers to it will fail to compile.

Invalid program (tries to define a function that allocates an incomplete type)

```
struct Foo;
template <class T> Foo* Create() { return new Foo; }
Foo* MyFoo = Create<int>();
struct Foo {};
```

Valid version of your program (move the function definition that allocates a Foo to the end):

```
struct Foo;
template <class T> Foo* Create();
Foo* MyFoo = Create<int>();
struct Foo {};
template <class T> Foo* Create() { return new Foo; }
```

That program compiles under g++, and to my knowledge is perfectly permissible. 
Relevant sections of the standard:

**5.3.1p1**
"indirection through a pointer to an incomplete type (other than cv void) is valid. The lvalue thus obtained can be used in limited ways (to initialize a reference, for example); this lvalue must not be converted to a prvalue"

**8.3.5p9**
"Types shall not be defined in return or parameter types. The type of a parameter or the return type for a function definition shall not be an incomplete class type"

Comment: Nope, not a valid program.

Comment: The code is not valid. If you think it is, you should provide relevant references from the C++ standard to back your claims up.

Comment: You're right, this is not a valid program at all -- I totally missed the initial (invalid) function definition in defending the function declaration after it.

Comment: @chmod_007: It's perfectly legal to define a template function using incomplete types.  The types must only be complete at the point of instantiation.

Comment: @PeterRuderman I think that is only the case for the template parameter (in this case, `T`). Not for an incomplete type that was forward declared elsewhere. An attempt to compile that under g++ produces:
`error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct Foo’` 
and
`error: forward declaration of ‘struct Foo’`

Comment: Did you try:
struct Foo;
template <class T> Foo* Create() { return new Foo; }
struct Foo {};
Foo* MyFoo = Create<int>();

Comment: Yes; that yields the same two errors (at lines 2 and 1). Have you compiled this? What compiler are you using? I admittedly don't know anything about the specifics of MSVC, but I'm pretty sure this code is not valid ISO C++.